# JSON- categorical data

Tags: json

I am writing a JSON file which holds data about electronics such as tvs, consoles etc. What is the best way to categorize, let's say 3D LED tvs, from non 3D LED tvs ?  Would it make more sense to put a property `'3d'` within an `'leds'` object ? Or is it better to create a `'3d'` object within `'leds'` ?

```
{"products":[
     { "tvs":[
        {"samsung":[
             {"leds":[
                 {
                 "product_id": "034567",
                 "product_name": "Samsung UA22F5100 22'' LED TV (Black)",
                 "model_no": "UA22F5100",
                 "brand": "Samsung",
                 "price": 399,
                 "screen_size": 22,
                 "screen_res": "1920 x 1080",
                 "usb": 1,
                 "hdmi": 1,
                 "screen_format": "LED",
                 "dimensions": "513.1 x 366.5 x 169.6",
                 "manuf_guarantee": "1 year"                  
                }
             ]}                
        ]}

    ]}
]}
```

Comment: I would try both and I would choose the smallest one

Comment: You could argue that `3d` should be a subset of `tvs` for example, or that `tvs` should be a subset of `samsung`. There are many ways to do this - choose a peg, hang your hat on it.

Comment: @rpax thanks for the comment! Ok, and which one would you think is easiest for traversing to objects? Is a lot of nesting, normal in JSON files?

Comment: From my point of view: smallest the size of the json -> faster the transfer of it. wouldn't care about the transversion.

Comment: @MikeW I see what you.. It all depends on what sort of data is required and how will the file is to be used. thanks for clarifying Cheers